# schemacrawler java.lang.NullPointerException: Catalog could not be retrieved

Tags: java, h2, hsqldb, schemacrawler

I try to use schemacrawler with hsqldb 2.51 and h2 2.x with the following code:

```
final LimitOptionsBuilder limit = LimitOptionsBuilder.builder()
    .includeSchemas(new IncludeAll())
    .includeTables(new IncludeAll());
final LoadOptionsBuilder load = LoadOptionsBuilder.builder()
    .withSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.minimum());
final SchemaCrawlerOptions options = SchemaCrawlerOptionsBuilder.newSchemaCrawlerOptions()
    .withLimitOptions(limit.toOptions())
    .withLoadOptions(load.toOptions());
final Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection, options);
// throw NullPointerException
for (final schemacrawler.schema.Table t : catalog.getTables())
{
    //more code...
}
```

I can't get the catalog without an NullPointerException error.
I have two archives in the classpath:

- schemacrawler-16.16.11.jar
- schemacrawler-hsqldb-16.16.11.jar

If someone has an idea...

Comment: is your connection null? I tried your code out, and I get a "ExecutionRuntimeException: No matching schemas found". You should not be excluding all schemas, because you will not get any tables.

Comment: @ Sualeh, My connection is not null for sure, it's the catalog who is null. I fixed the `new ExcludeAll()` sorry it's a typo...If I use this typo code I always have a "NullPointerException" never "No matching schemas found". If I use the CatalogLoader and print it it's seem to be empty: `CatalogLoader [[]]`

Comment: @Sualeh I use SchemaCrawler in a JDBC driver for LibreOffice to make it agnostic (connection.getMetaData, ResultSetMetaData...) and to be able to offer different Database (HsqlDB, H2).
Can you tell me where to look?

Answer (score 0):

After changing some code I managed to have something that works...

```
new LoggingConfig(Level.ALL);
final LimitOptionsBuilder limit = LimitOptionsBuilder.builder()
    .includeSchemas(new IncludeAll())
    .includeTables(new IncludeAll());
final LoadOptionsBuilder load = LoadOptionsBuilder.builder()
    .withSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.minimum());
final SchemaCrawlerOptions options = SchemaCrawlerOptionsBuilder.newSchemaCrawlerOptions()
    .withLimitOptions(limit.toOptions())
    .withLoadOptions(load.toOptions()); 
final SchemaRetrievalOptions retrieval = SchemaCrawlerUtility.matchSchemaRetrievalOptions(connection);
schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler crawler = new schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler(connection, retrieval, options);
final Catalog catalog = crawler.crawl();
for (final schemacrawler.schema.Table t : catalog.getTables())
    {
        //more code...
    }
```

However, the first code always gives me the same error...

Comment: Very hard to tell what you are doing with a few lines of code and no stack trace. I am glad you got it working, though.